# Is there a way to wrap text and image into one checkbox element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to wrap some text and an image into a checkbox, so when the user clicks the image or text the whole area gets highlighted. Is it possible to do it in javascript?

I tried to illustrate what I want to do below:

[image: Illustration]

```
      <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
        <div className="col-1" style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}><input type="checkbox" id="test1" value={this.state.test1} checked={this.state.test1} onChange={() => { this.setState({ test1: !this.state.test1}) }} /></div>
        <div className="col-2"><label htmlFor="test1"><img alt="test1" src={require('../static/image.png')} /></label></div>
        <div className="col-4"><label htmlFor="test1"><b>{this.props.t('here is some text')}</b>:<br />{this.props.t('and some more')}. {this.props.t('hello!')}.</label></div>
      </div>
```

This is the code I have so far with the checkbox.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: simple answer is YES, try to add something like `{ this.state.test1 ? selectedStyleProperties : ''}` to the style of the container of yore checkbox element.

Comment: Could you please specify what would be in `selectedStyleProperties` place and `' '` ?

Comment: selectedStyleProperties i meant your style for example `const selectedStyleProperties = {borderColor: 'green'}` and `' '` is an empty string or you can put your unselected style.

Comment: or you can do the same withe className `className={this.state.test1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}`

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="items" style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black'></div>
<div class="items" style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow'></div>
<div class="items" style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background: gray'></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('items');

for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
   (function () {
      items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        for(var j=0; j < items.length; j++){
          items[j].style.border = 'none';
          items[j].style.borderRadius = '0px';
        }
        this.style.border = '1px solid green';
        this.style.borderRadius = '10px';

      }, false);
   })();
}
```

Comment: Slight typo in your example HTML - each `/div` is missing a left-angle-bracket